# Means to get the actual release version code of my application

Tags: android

Is there a means to programmatically get the actual release version code of my application published on the store ?

From my developer console, I can manually get the version code, but I want to obtain this number using a URL for instance.

Actually, my method of substitution is to create an Apache/PHP URL returning directly the version Code that I entered manually :

```
<?php /* File getVersionCode.php */

$versionCode = 24;
return "Version code of production is ".$versionCode; 

?>
```

And when I call my URL mysite/getVersionCode.php , I automatically get the following return :

```
Version code of production is 24
```

Is there a way to obtain it differently, by accessing a google URL for example ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the version code inside the application programatically.

```
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName;
```

Comment: My aim is to know this version Code when I release a new version, so I can be sure of my APK generated version code, in order to release it afterwards. I must get this information from a different environment from Android

Comment: what do you mean by `different environment `?

Comment: I want to automatically "ant release" my apk, and automatically set the versionCode of my AndroidManifest to the correct value (corresponding to the value of the released one +1), thus, I need to know for sure what number corresponds actually to the released version. I can do this manually, but I want to know if there is another way to do so !